# Is There A Single-Word For Describing Someone Who Sticks To Their Guns?

Tags: single-word-requests

My question is this: Is there a single-word to describe my actions or to describe a person who sticks to their guns?

I recently encountered an issue with a seller online. The goods were shipped over two months ago. I did a shipping inquiry through USPS and received a formal letter from them two days ago stating that they lost the package and that since it's lost it will still display as being in transit. I contacted the seller asking for a refund and attached a copy of the letter from USPS.

Their response: "Dear, why they think lost? Still in transit."

I asked for a refund and they refused. So, I opened a dispute.

The sellers response to the dispute: "Dear, close dispute bad for business logistics in transit. Sob sob sob"

My response: "I will close the dispute when you provide me with a guarantee in writing that I will receive a full refund when the package hasn't arrived by a specified date. USPS has already informed me that they lost the package, please see the attached letter that I provided two days ago."

The sellers response: "Dear, why they think lost? Still in transit. Please close dispute. Sob sob sob"

My response: "As previously stated, I will close the dispute when you provide me with a guarantee in writing that I will receive a full refund when the package hasn't arrived by a specified date. USPS has already informed me that they lost the package, please see the attached letter that I provided two days ago."

The sellers response: "Dear, please close dispute wait patiently for logistics. Sob sob sob"

Comment: Hi. Thanks for contributing. All the details of your dispute with this company don't add anything to your question. Could you please remove them, and maybe instead explain more about the word you are looking for? Are you looking for a word with positive or negative connotations?

Comment: Have you checked https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/stubborn ?

Comment: So who’s sticking to their guns here? You? The seller? Or both?  You are being persistent. They are being obstinate.